# Paypal digital goods checkout rejects valid user logins

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

**Background:**

I'm using the Paypal Express Digital Goods workflow [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/digital-goods/IntegratingExpressCheckoutDG/).
My application allows users to buy some credits (a digital good).
I've set up the checkout process successfully in sandbox mode, and have valid credentials for live mode.

On my live app, when I try to check out using a valid PayPal account, the pop-up cart rejects my user login as follows:

[image]

- I am absolutely sure that I have entered the correct username and password (if I close the window and just open a new browser tag, I can log into PayPal using the exact same credentials).
- If it helps, the user I am trying to log in (myself) has two-factor authentication enabled on PayPal.

---

**Question**

**What might be causing this to happen?** (or better yet, how do I fix this?) I have no idea how to debug this given that the rejection is happening server-side at PayPal.

thanks very much in advance.